# diesel powered heating - identification and advice request

Tags: electrical, boiler, generator, central-heating

I bought a house and the owner is a few steps removed from the last user of the house which leaves me at a loss as to who I even need to speak to about the machines and systems.

My hope is that I can decipher whats going on by posting the images and details here. PS I have had 2 local experts come around and give me totally different assessments and suggest 'it will be costly' (to very different amounts) to deal with it.

I have found a room with a large machine that seems to have used to run the heating and electrics which I believe is powered by diesel because there is an underground diesel reservoir which has a lot of diesel still there for decades i think.

There are some huge Viessmann Machines in there and a load of fuses which seemingly do nothing as i can switch them around without affecting anything.

What on earth is all of this and can it simply be removed?

Can anyone technical or knowledgable please help me try to figure out what I'm dealing with?
[image: main console]

see full gallery below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdQJA.jpg

Comment: https://www.viessmann.de/de/services/bedienungsanleitungen.html

Comment: Does it turn on? How is the house heated now? To research this, you absolutely need to contact Viesmann and get an users manual and installation manual. That will give you a start in the right direction.   The pics you provided were great, but without more info, it'll take a lot of detective work to see what affects what. You also mentioned it running the "electrics" is part of this contraption a backup generator?   Where are you? it looks German,  also, hate to tell you but diesel only lasts for at most 2 years before it goes bad.   You have to figure it out before you can simply remove it.

Comment: Info https://www.bedienungsanleitung24.de/viessmann-trimatik-mc

Comment: the lights go on but not much else happens. I'm in the swiss itallian border.  I had a guy offer me a deal to spend 2000Euros to help me understand what was going on... then the other guy said he's fix it all for 10k... total joke and it's countryside around here so slim pickings for options

Comment: Veissmann, and companies, have their own techs that will come and advise you. They will need to be paid BUT they will know the equipment, compared to any local "guy" that you might find. I know that these techs exist as I live in CH as well and I see them driving about (also worked with some).

Comment: The company also may have users manuals online, of available for a minimal fee. But if you've just bought the house (didn't you ask about the heating system before making that decision?) you had best assume that the boiler is at least due for its yearly maintenance. Also, that big oil tank really will need to be refilled periodically; in the US when you sign a contract with an oil delivery service that usually comes with discounted, or at least priority, maintenance and repair services.

Comment: The manual for the control unit is available here: https://www.libble.de/viessmann-trimatik-mc---7450-261a/p/824412/

Comment: You probably want to grab manuals for the rest of the system as well, for your own education even if you wind up paying someone to do an initial maintenance pass over it. I wouldn't muck with my gas boiler (beyond the thermostat interface, anyway) but I read through the docs so I could better understand how it works and how to do some initial diagnostics before calling the technician.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's presumably a diesel-powered generator; unless it's a weirdly packaged oil-fired boiler (home heating oil and diesel being essentially the same thing.) A wise use of a generator in this role is to take the waste heat and use it for heating as well, in heating season for a cold climate, since you are burning the fuel anyway and it saves on the amount of electricity you need to heat the house.

How it's hooked up is hardly clear from the pictures linked here.

Removing it should be quite possible and should involve someone paying you large sums of money, not the other way around. You might regret doing so when the power goes out, as it probably does from time to time; the expense of putting such a system in implies non-trivial power outages. When one of those happens in winter, having the plumbing freeze up makes them very expensive to recover from.

Comment: I was tempted, after buying the house, to put in a gas-fired cogeneration/heating system; those were just starting to become available in residential sizes... But at the time they would only interface with forced-air heating, not hydronic, so I didn't get to take that gamble.

Comment: Yeah, I got sidetracked by the promise of residential fuel cells, which turned out to be pure vaporware and blatant lies. What little has ever come out of that is 10X the price points they were claiming, making it utterly non-viable, and they never had a propane option anyway (no NG where I am, nor likely ever will be unless I decide to drill a 5,000-12,000 foot well, which is likewise not economically feasible. Ended up connected tothe grid after all [which I was initially refused on, but they got much more flexible with the (2008?) economic downturn and I still had money.]